# Convert text to image?

Tags: php, image-processing

I have seen in a couple of cases when sites generate image based on text/data input.  How that can be achieved with PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [libGD](http://libgd.org) is one of the most popular alternatives for generating images (and it has bindings for most languages used in web development).

See the documentation on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). I guess you are especially interested in [imagettftext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php).

Answer (score 4):

Another option: try [imagick](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick)

Answer (score 3):

## Working Solution:

( at first, you need to ensure, that the hosting has enabled GD library: in any  php file, execute `phpinfo();` and in output check if GD library is enabled) .

## Solution 1 (auto-sized output):

```
TextToImage_my( $text='Helloooo! my unicode words:  ǩ Ƥ Ў  ض ط  Ⴓ ');
    // ==== other parameters can be used too, see the function arguments below
```

function code: [text-to-image.php](https://github.com/tazotodua/useful-php-scripts/blob/master/text-to-image.php)

## Solution 2 (manual-sized output):

(needs to have manual width&height of output,  longer strings are cut out)..

```
<?php
$text = "YOUR  texttttttttttttttt";

$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );                             //width & height
$background  = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0,   0,   255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, $text, $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
?>
```

Comment: imagepng( $my_img,"text2imge_filename.png" ); file " text2imge_filename.png" will be created on server and you can display the text in image format using this name . This important information is not displayed found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233834/convert-php-string-to-image

Answer (score 2):

Using [gd](http://www.php.net/gd) or other such libraries (or libraries built on top of gd).

Answer (score 1):

The PHP GD extension allows text to be overlaid on an image.

In fact, you don't need an image in the first place, you can generate an image containing just the text.

I've used it for buttons.